# form_for not accepting html in devise loop? (Devise rails gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

i'm trying to use devise to accept forms from multiple views to my database, i've essentially split devise between 3 views, 1 works great using the 1st paragraph of code below and accepts html. However using the HTML on my other views causes my app to break with either "2 arguments, expected 0" or "1st argument cannot be nil". I'm a little lost because i know devise is reading from the database since it works fine -without- the HTML. Any ideas?

code works on 1st view but all other views it does not (unless html is removed)-

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put, class: "form floating-label" }) do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

what code looks like when html is removed (current_user) allows me to use the code on multiple pages so is required. I want to have to code look like the one above.

```
<%= form_for current_user, { url: registration_path(resource_name), method: :patch } do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: that moment when your questions become to hard for stackoverflow

Comment: to anyone reading this thread for help, custom form_for in devise will only work assuming routes are setup and you have inherited your devise controller. By default devise does not show the controller but you can generate one to inherit to it simply and add the changes you need, then tell your routes to go to that controller. Once all that is done you can use the form_for syntax below (or above) throughout your views as necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Both* `resource` and `resource_name` are defined by the devise controller and won't be accessible outside of a Devise view. However, if a user isn't signed in then `current_user` in place of `resource` won't work either since it's nil.

The following should work if `current_user` is present:

```
<%= form_for(current_user, as: :user, url: registration_path(:user), html: { method: :put, class: "form floating-label" }) do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

As long as `devise_for :users` is defined in your routes.

Comment: Getting same error "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty", my routes are set correctly with

     devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'users/registrations'}
     as :user do 
       get 'users/changepassword' => 'devise/registrations#changepassword'

Comment: current_user is always defined by devise

Comment: Always defined, yes, but not always non-`nil`. It wouldn't be possible to get that error otherwise. It seems as though no user is currently signed in, hence the nil value for `current_user`.